# Facebook access_token expires after 2 hours

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

PHP script successfully get feeds from my Facebook page:

```
    $access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/711493158867950/feed?access_token='.$access_token;
    $curl = curl_init();

    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $json = curl_exec($curl);
```

But after two hours access_token expires and I get the following error:http://prntscr.com/60jyqt.
How to rewrite the following php code to "renew" access_token key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with having a look at the documentation:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Facebook SDK v3.1):

1) Create a "system user"

2) Grant him access to the properties I needed (in my case an App)

3) Generate a new token for that app and system user

The instructions I used can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api/systemuser)